# Google Adsense: how can I break down the number of clicks by advert on the reports

Tags: adsense

I have a webpage where I have 3 ads that I have set up on Google Adsense.

I would love to be able to know how many clicks they generate individually.

On the report section, I can get only the total number of clicks.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

If so, how?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I have found the answer. You have to create a channel and then edit your ad unit (from the 'Manage Ads' menu link). At the bottom of the edit page you will find how to add an ad unit to a channel.

Comment: dan - post you your own answer and accept it please